# how to use directives to enable a disabled button in angular 4

Tags: angular

How can i use directives to enable a disabled button. For example

*Here is my html code*

```
<button appHighlight >Increment</button>
<button appHighlight disabled>decrement</button>
```

Here appHighlight is my directive. I want that when i click increment button my decrement button gets enabled.

Here is my directive code. I want to use host listner for this. I don't know how to do this.

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[appHighlight]',
})
export class HighlightDirective {

    constructor(private el: ElementRef ) { }

    numberOfClicks = 0;
    showMainContent: Boolean = true;

    @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
    ShowHideButton(btn) {
        console.log('button', btn, 'number of clicks:', 
        this.numberOfClicks++);

   }
}
```

Comment: Post your directive's code.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what your directives code looks like.
You could use the angular property for disabled instead.

```
<button appHighlight (click)="incrementClicked = true">Increment</button>
<button appHighlight [disabled]="incrementClicked">decrement</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The directive can also be written like this

```
    <button appHighlight >Increment</button>
<button appHighlight disabled="true">decrement</button>
```

So you can play with a boolean variable to disable or enable your decrement button.